# Maximum Modulus of Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

here's a question I'm working on that I'm a bit stuck on.
Let: 
$f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z + 2}$
Find the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ as $z$ varies over the unit disc.

Since $f(z)$ is analytic $\forall z$ in the region,and $f(z)$ is non-constant, the maximum of this function will be on the boundary of the unit disc (Is this the correct application of the theorem?)
If we let $z = e^{it}$ then 
$|f(e^{it})| = \frac{|e^{it}|^2}{|e^{it} + 2|}$ 
 $|f(e^{it})| = \frac{1}{|e^{it} + 2|}$

However, I'm stuck here. 
The answer given is $1$, but I'm not quite sure how to figure that out. There's quite a bit of confusion on my end as well, as I'm not fully certain if I'm on the right track.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Uhm... I wonder how we could maximise $\frac{1}{\lvert e^{it}+2\rvert}$ over $t\in[0,2\pi]$. If only it were a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ maybe I could do it...

Comment: If you want to maximize $\frac {1}{|e^{it} + 2|}$ you will want to minimize $|e^{it} + 2|$

Comment: Would it be: $\frac{1}{|e^{it} + 2|} \leq \frac{1}{|e^{it}|} = 1$ ?

Comment: @user2965071 Since $1$ is the answer, then that inequality is true. I don't see how you prove that $\lvert e^{it}+2\rvert\ge \lvert e^{it}\rvert$, though.

Comment: $|2+e^{it}|=|2+\cos t +i \sin t| $ which means that for $t=\pi$ you get $|2+e^{it}|=min=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum of $\mid e^{it}+2\mid$ pretty clearly occurs when $t=\pi$.  That is,  the maximum modulus is $1$.

You did the problem correctly (up to there).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do this by common sense: you want to maximize $\frac{1}{|e^{it} + 2|}$, which means minimizing $|e^{it} + 2|$, so draw the picture, and find a complex number on the unit circle whose distance from $z=-2$ is minimum.

Comment: I like this kind of geometrical argument.